# DLT table created in target is not queryable

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, delta-live-tables

I've created a DLT table by specifying database in the target, but while querying the same using SQL endpoint, its throwing exception.
'Failure to initialize configuration'

Please note that source is defined as ADLS. The DLT table should be queryable.

metastore is hive_metastore catalog

Comment: do you have correct configuration of the service principal, etc. in the DBSQL admin console?

Comment: Hi @Ravindra Please add more information and error message with your code.

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt I missed to configure SP in SQL admin console settings.
[Data access configuration - Azure Databricks - Databricks SQL | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/admin/data-access-configuration#storage-access)

Comment: yes, it's typical. Here is answer about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74375042/databricks-sql-database-creation-with-location-azure-data-lake/74376819#74376819