# Databricks SQL database creation with location Azure Data Lake

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

How to create a database in Databricks hive metastore with location adls and abfss (without mounting) ?

Something like this

```
create database if not exists adb_raw
location "abfss://container@stgaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/01_RAW/flat_files/"
```

will return error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.KeyProviderException Failure to initialize configuration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide configuration parameters for ADLS authentication in the SQL Admin console as it's described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/admin/data-access-configuration#--configure-a-service-principal).

[image]

[image]

[image]